# C++ string management convert raw string through dictionary matching

Tags: c++

What this code does is that given a string, it will look through the array attached at the bottom so that if a string matches one of the array element, all new bits of a string is combined together to form a new string and then it gets returned! In other words, it converts a long and raw string by looking it up in the "dictionary" then return the interpreted new strnig.

I am trying to add some code at // comment so that if I encounter raw strings that don't match anything on record, as in the array, then it will call another function to deal with it. I am thinking about logging it so that I can updated the dictionary.

thanks!

```
string string_look_up(string data)
{
string loc_string = "";

std::stringstream ss(data);

std::string line;
while (std::getline(ss, line, '0'))
{
    if (line.empty())
    {
        continue;
    }

    cout << line << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 82; i++)
    {
        if (line == dictionary_array_strings_raw[i])
        {
            loc_string = loc_string + dictionary_array_strings_digits[i];
        }

    }

    /// this is where the new code I want should be

    cout << loc_string << endl;
    cout << "######" << endl;
}

return loc_string;
}

const string dictionary_array_strings_raw[] = { // x
                                                "25643663",
                                                // Y
                                                "2346442", "2446442",
                                                // Z
                                                "3676764",
                                                // :
                                                "4",
                                                // -
                                                "111" }

const string dictionary_array_strings_digits[] = { // x
                                                   "X",
                                                   // Y
                                                   "Y", "Y",
                                                   // Z
                                                   "Z",
                                                   // :
                                                   ":",
                                                   // -
                                                   "-",
                                                   // 1  }
```

Comment: So.... what's the *question* ?

Comment: I am not sure how to add a If/else check to return the string not in the dictionary, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `std::find` to locate the raw string within the array. To get the index for the digits array just subtract the begin of the array from the iterator returned by std::find.

std::find requires two iterators (begin and end) for the search range. Plain pointers can be used as iterators (because they support incrementing (++) and dereferencing (*)). The return value is either an interator pointing to the first element found or an end-iterator pointing to the end (one past the last element).

The std::function parameter allows you to specify a callback for lines not found in the raw string array. You can use any function or lambda that matches the signature (`const std::string&` parameter and `std::string` return value).

**WARNING**: The following code is not correct. It uses 82 for the number of dictionary entries (like the code from the original post) but it defines only 6 dictionary entries. This will result in undefined behaviour if using unknown raw strings. You should add 76 dictionary entries or reduce the entry-count from 82 to 6.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

const string dictionary_array_strings_raw[] = { // x
    "25643663",
    // Y
    "2346442", "2446442",
    // Z
    "3676764",
    // :
    "4",
    // -
    "111"
};

const string dictionary_array_strings_digits[] = { // x
    "X",
    // Y
    "Y", "Y",
    // Z
    "Z",
    // :
    ":",
    // -
    "-",
    // 1  
};

string string_look_up(string data, std::function<std::string(const std::string&)> callback)
{
    assert(callback != nullptr);

    const auto dictionary_array_strings_raw_end = dictionary_array_strings_raw + 82;

    std::string loc_string = "";

    std::stringstream ss(data);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(ss, line, '0'))
    {
        if (line.empty())
        {
            continue;
        }

        cout << line << endl;
        const auto it = std::find(dictionary_array_strings_raw, dictionary_array_strings_raw_end, line);

        if (it == dictionary_array_strings_raw_end)
            loc_string += callback(line);
        else
            loc_string += dictionary_array_strings_digits[it - dictionary_array_strings_raw];

        cout << loc_string << endl;
        cout << "######" << endl;
    }

    return loc_string;
}
```

The following example shows the use of a lambda for unknown raw strings ('99' in the example).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const auto result = string_look_up("25643663023464420990", [](const std::string& line) { return '<' + line + '>'; });
    std::cout << "Result:\n" << result;

    return 0;
}
```

When string_look_up encounters the line containing '99' it tries to find a matching raw-string. When it does not find a matching raw string it calls the callback-function with "99" as its only parameter. The lambda defined in main adds '<' before and '>' after the line value and returns the result to string_look_up() which adds the return value to the result.

The input `25643663023464420990` results in the output `XY<99>` (and a lot of debug output)

I would recommend using a std::map for the translation table (raw strings as keys, digits as values). With a map you could use the find() member function to get the iterator (let's call it 'it') and it->second to get the digits string.

Here is an example for the static initialization of a map:

```
const std::map<std::string, std::string> translationTable = {
    {"25643663", "X"},
    {"2346442", "Y"},
    {"2446442", "Y" }
    // ...
};
```

You can search for a value with `const auto it = translationTable.find(line);` and compare it to `translationTable.end()` to check if the search was successfull. `it->first` contains the raw string (i.e. "25643663") while `it->second` contains the digits string (i.e. "X")

Answer (score -1):

Have a bool flag for the loop. If you find a match, set it to true. Then, you can place a check where your comment is.

```
if(flag)
{
//code if found
}
else
{
//code if not found
}
```